# D3.js get the rendered dimensions of a tree when nodeSize is specified

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm rendering a tree layout with d3.js. I need to use the nodeSize option because the number of nodes and breadth/depth is widely variable (data is loaded dynamically). Now I have an image export feature too, and I would like to be able to dynamically resize the SVG canvas according to the final tree to make it "best fit" to the canvas, resulting a nice looking image output.

Is there any way to get/compute/query the final tree size after the tree has been rendered?

Comment: provide your code ! or your work

Comment: you can put it on jsfiddle

Comment: The code is tightly coupled with my data structure, but the code should not matter too much here, one can use the demo of D3 for example. The question is not related to coding IMO. I'm examining a technique just right now, so probably I'm gonna find the way.

Comment: Assuming that all of the tree is contained within a `g` element, you can simply call `.getBBox()` on that element, which will give you its bounding box.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Thank you for the tip, I'm not familiar with native SVG too much. Could you point to some link about browser support for this method? Is it well supported in all modern browsers? Actually what I've done is something similar, iterated through every element and calculated the min/max coordinates.

Comment: As far as I know it's fairly universally supported.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Finally I had time to test the getBBox method, and it worked fine. I would like to close this so please post a short answer based on your comment, so I can accept it. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that all of the tree is contained within a `g` element, you can simply call `.getBBox()` on that element, which will give you its bounding box. This will tell you the rendered dimensions among other things.

Answer (score 0):

One method you should be able to do is to loop through each node, grab the highest and lowest x or y values, and then subtract them. I was using a [cluster](https://devdocs.io/d3%7E6/d3-hierarchy#cluster_size) instead of a tree, but I believe both provide methods for doing this. Also there is a node.sort method, so another approach could be to sort the nodes by the x value to get the lowest and highest x values, and then do the same for y.